# Can I force Safari to always show bookmark names, not webpage titles?

Tags: safari, bookmarks

I have several bookmarks for finance.yahoo.com. Each bookmark lists a series of stock tickers that I am watching. I gave the bookmark unique names that makes them easy to identify (e.g. "$-Investments".)

If I go to Safari's location field and start typing "finance", there is a popup list with a Bookmarks section, but the bookmarks are listed with the cached webpage title and the URL. What I want to see in the bookmarks section is the bookmark name instead of the cached webpage title. How can I make this happen every time, without having to use drastic measures like private browsing, emptying the cache, or resetting Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar workflow that I've used in Safari and I've used the Edit Name Feature to make it easier to move from one site to another.

If I bring up a chart of SSO in Stockcharts.com and create a Bookmark, the Bookmarks Toolbar Menu shows it as SSO - Stockcharts Workbench - Stockcharts.Com.

Then I "Show All Bookmarks", right-click (control click) edit the name SSO - Stockcharts Workbench - Stockcharts.Com to be just SSO.

This now appears as SSO on my bookmark toolbar list.  To switch to this bookmark, I can choose it under the Bookmarks menu or Bookmarks Toolbar.  What I usually do is use Cmd L which highlights the address bar, type SSO and Safari displays a short list of History and Bookmarks.  I scroll down to SSO under Bookmarks and hit "Enter" for my SSO chart.  This bypasses using the mouse and gets me right to the chart with just a few keystrokes.

As another example, I get to Apple with CMD L, AAPL, cursor down to AAPL site I want and hit Enter.

Here's a screenshot for AAPL with several bookmarked sites that include AAPL.

[image: AAPL Screenshot]

I like using Cmd L for two reasons.  I can move from one bookmark to another without needing to use my mouse or trackpad.  Plus the shortened SSO Name sits on my Bookmark Toolbar using much less space than if I added it to the Toolbar with the original bookmark title.

Comment: Ah, I think what you're saying is to start typing the name of the bookmark in the location bar rather than the hostname part of the URL. That works! All of the bookmarks I care about for this particular set start with the character "$", so I can type "$" in the location bar and see all of my similarly-named financial bookmarks.